# Best practices to assert current_user_can() with guests

Tags: security, capabilities, customization

In WordPress, a guest can do a lot of things, such as reading posts.

However, this always returns false for guests:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
    global $post;

    /** @var WP_Post_Type $pto */
    $pto = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post->ID));

    /** @var bool $cap */
    $cap = current_user_can($pto->cap->read_post);
});
```

I see that `current_user_can()` triggers this piece of code for guests:

```
// wp-includes/user.php @ line 2613 (WordPress 5.0.0)
wp_set_current_user( 0 );
return $current_user;
```

Thus running assertions on this `WP_User` object:

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [ID] => 0
    [caps] => Array
        (
        )

    [cap_key] => 
    [roles] => Array
        (
        )

    [allcaps] => Array
        (
        )

    [filter] => 
    [site_id:WP_User:private] => 0
)
```

Which means it has no capability at all, probably why it's failing.

Given that a guest can actually read a post, why this returns false?

Being such assertions critical for security, how can I assert if a guest is allowed to do something in WordPress, such as reading a post type, or a post ID?

Comment: The 'read' capability requires authentication, and is for allowing access to the WordPress dashboard and the user's profile page - see [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#read).

Comment: @SallyCJ The first paragraph from the linked resource says "to control what users can and cannot do" - this implies roles and capabilities have nothing to do with guests (and hence `current_user_can()` always returns `false` for a guest). Am I wrong?

Comment: For standard Posts (`post` post type), the `current_user_can($pto->cap->read)` in the code is equivalent to `current_user_can( 'read' )`; so looking at what the 'read' capability is for, I think it's normal for guests to have no 'read' capability despite they can of course freely do things like read posts, post comments, etc. that *don't* need capabilities which require authentication or special cookie/session. That's what I was trying to say @kero. But do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, thanks for the clarifiction on "read" capability. I have removed that from the example code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SallyCJ The problem is, `read_posts` returns `false` as well. And I suspect everything will return false for a guest. As I said, I think roles & capabilities is the wrong place to check anything for a guest

Comment: @LucasBustamante What exactly is it, you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @kero I have a concrete example of something I'm trying to achieve, however, I would like to keep the scope of the question to an abstract problem of guest capability assertion.

Comment: I don't have the time now to dig deeper, but as I see it right now the answer would be: guests have no capabilities. Also it seems, capabilities are used most of the time in the backend (and since guests can't access the backend, they don't need capabilities)

Comment: @kero, I think my first comment was because I misunderstood I thought that Lucas *also* asked why the `current_user_can( 'read' )` returns `false`.

Comment: @LucasBustamante, I'm agreeing with kero's previous comment - guests have no capabilities. Capabilities are assigned to user roles, and since guests don't have any roles, they don't have any capabilities. And by default, if the post type object has `map_meta_cap` set to `true`, the `read_post` cap maps to `read` *if* the post status is public - and by "public", I'm referring to the `public` property of the post status [*object*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status_object/).

Comment: It might also be helpful to mention that custom post types registered with the `capability_type` set to `post` or `page` will have `map_meta_cap` set to `true` unless you explicitly set it to `false`.